# How can I deploy a react vite application with a public folder to a subfolder on my domain?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vite, rollupjs

I am trying to deploy a react application with vite as the bundler to a subfolder on my domain (i.e. https://example.com/my-app).

My `vite.config.ts` is as follows:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  root: "./",
  build: {
    outDir: "dist",
  },
  base: "/my-app/",
  publicDir: "public"
});
```

I'm deploying this as a static site, so I'm basically copying the `dist` folder from running `vite build` to my digital ocean droplet.

When I navigate to https://example.com/my-app, I am able to receive the initial javascript and css files. However, when the javascript runs, I get a 404 error on a file that is in the `public` folder. The `GET` request indicates that it is no longer looking in the subfolder, but looking for the asset directly in the root domain.

So, `GET` request for javascript looks like this:

`https://example.com/my-app/assets/index-95119c9d.js`

`GET` request based on the served javascript for the static asset (`my-asset`)looks like this:

`https://example.com/my-asset`

How do I indicate in my `vite.config.ts` that references to the `public` folder assets should *also* be searched for at the subfolder specified as `base` in my config file.

Comment: did u find any solution to this?

Comment: Been working on this problem forever. Thinking the solution/problem was within nginx. create-react-app has a built in solution in which you modify homepage:'*' before build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up needing to prefix all of the files I was loading from the "public" folder with the subfolder name (e.g. `/my-app/my-asset` from the example above). Doing this in combination with the above `vite.config.ts` worked, though I feel this is a brittle solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `base` in `vite` config:

https://github.com/antfu/vitesse/discussions/226